# How to kill all previous Firebase notifications when new notification comes in Objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase, push-notification

I want to kill/remove all previous Firebase push notifications when new Notification came from Firebase.
Because while I'm using the app, If I send one notification due to network Issue that notification haven't delivered, but when one moe notification sending time first one is receives to destination device.
I'm resetting the Notification Badge, but its not a right solution.
So Please suggest to achieve this